# Remove List Element Dynamically

Tags: javascript, dom

I plan to write a javascript code for a to do list that dynamically adds elements to the unordered list along with a remove button for each element. When the user clicks on the remove button, I would like to have the corresponding list element removed. How to remove the said list element dynamically

```
var button = document.querySelector("button");
var input = document.querySelector("input");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
button.addEventListener("click",function(){
    if((input.value.length)>0&&(input.value.includes("by")===true))
    {
        var li= document.createElement("li");
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value + " "));
        ul.appendChild(li);
        input.value="";
        var nb= document.createElement("button");
        nb.appendChild(document.createTextNode("REMOVE"));
        li.appendChild(nb);
    }
    else if(input.value.includes("by")===false)
    {
        alert("Make Sure You Adhere to the Defined Format");
    }
});
```

Comment: On click of the button, get the closest `li` element, and remove it.

Comment: find the parentNode of the target element and call the `removeChild()` method. example:

`li.parentNode.removeChild(li);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an onclick handler and on click of the button get the `parentNode` and use `remove` to remove it

```js
var button = document.querySelector("button");
var input = document.querySelector("input");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if ((input.value.length) > 0 && (input.value.includes("by") === true)) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value + " "));
    ul.appendChild(li);
    input.value = "";
    var nb = document.createElement("button");
    //nb.classList.add('remove');
    nb.onclick = removeThis; // added onclick handler
    nb.appendChild(document.createTextNode("REMOVE"));
    li.appendChild(nb);
  } else if (input.value.includes("by") === false) {
    alert("Make Sure You Adhere to the Defined Format");
  }
});


function removeThis() {
  this.parentNode.remove();
}
```

```html
<ul></ul>
<input type='text'><button type='button'>Add</button>
```